# How to get name and pic of ACTORS from IMDB, inside an Android App

Tags: android, html-parsing, imdb

I need to get the name and picture of an actor from his page on IMDB. I know nothing about this process, especially on Android. I'm not asking for precise code (even if it would be wonderful), but at least a link to some good tutorial.
Here is a link to an example: [Liam Neeson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000553/)
Given i can do this, is it legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/search-people rather than scrapping.

Answer (score 0):

See `License and Site Access` at the [IMDb Terms of use](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions), use [The Movie Db](http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/search-people) like Utopiah suggests as IMDb forbids data scraping.